# Are there any equivalent of CSS max-width, border-radius, box-shadow and -...-transition in HTML?

Tags: html, css

In my website, it looks great on any browser but Internet Explorer.  I know that older versions Internet Explorer doesn't support CSS3, so I was wondering if there were equivalents in HTML to these methods: `max-width:`, `border-radius:`, `box-shadow:`, and `transition:`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not without using javascript or images.

Comment: IE9 supports all of the things you mentioned, except transitions.

Comment: I know this, but I'm talking about earlier versions of IE.  I want to make it viewable on pre-IE9 versions.

Comment: There is a primitive box shadow in IE filters, which is ok for basic shadowing. There is also some way/plug-in to simulate rounded corners for IE but I think I opted out because it was too much code for a property. no idea on max-width and transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `border-radius` and `box-shadow` there is http://css3pie.com/ but that requires Javascript in IE. For a HTML only solution you have to use images, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a way to get some of the newer features of CSS rendered in a browser that doesn't support CSS (or let's hope you are ignoring browsers that old and instead working with a browser version that do some CSS, but not enough for your tastes). Those browsers are outdated and you are not going to get it work just by avoiding css.

If you go far enough back, you may actually end up at a point in time when there were things that were possible in html weren't in css. However, it has been quite a while now that CSS is your best shot at getting things like that to work. If it doesn't work, it usually means that the browser doesn't support it at all, not that it doesn't support it through CSS.

Of course, you can work some magic and try to fake things with javascript, but it just isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).  It detects if a browser supports different css3 (and html5) features and, if it doesn't, you can conditionally load javascript as a fallback solution.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 9 supports `max-width`, `border-radius` and `box-shadow`, but not `transition`.

Personally I don't think CSS should have `transition` (or `animation`) as styles should affect how content is displayed, not how it behaves (I am also against the `behaviour` IE extension for this reason).

Overall, these styles you are asking for are aesthetical, and shouldn't really be a major issue if they aren't supported by the browser your user is on.